# AngularJS with ui-router ng-hide not working after initially working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been struggling with a ng-hide issue in combination with using ui-router. Simple app. Index.html shows some data via the "notes" route, you click on "detail" and you go to the sub route "notes.note" to view the detail just below the other records. The "detail" html has a "Save" & "Cancel" button.

Now there is an "Add New" button when you are not viewing the detail with the attribute ***ng-hide="HideAddNew"***. "HideAddNew" is a $scope variable in the controller. When I click "detail" on a row I have this ***ng-click="toggleAddNew()"*** on the link which in turn calls this

```
    $scope.toggleAddNew= function()
    {
        $scope.HideAddNew=($scope.HideAddNew ? false : true);
    }
```

That works perfectly, my detail shows and my "Add New" button has disappeared. Now on the detail when I click "Cancel" it fire off the ***ng-click="hideData()"*** which calls the function:

```
   $scope.hideData=function()
   {
        $scope.toggleAddNew();
        $state.go('notes');
   }
```

And now my "Add New" has disappeared even though the variable is set to false, i.e. Don't hide. I've tried $timeout in that "**hideData**" function and in the "**toggleAddNew**" function. I've tried putting ***"$scope.toggleAddNew();"*** after the ***"$state.go('notes');"*** too. I don't want to resort to manually adding and removing classes. AngularJS ver: **v1.3.15** , ui-router ver: **v0.2.13** Thanx all :)

**EDIT**
Would the below work Tony?

```
 <button ng-if="HideAddNew" ng-click="SelectRoute('notenew')" class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus -glyphicon-align-left"></span>Add New</button>
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `ng-switch` in the template instead of the `$scope.HideAddNew` you have in the controller right now? Alternatively, you could try adding `$scope.HideAddNew = false;` in the `hideData` function.

Comment: I've tried adding  "$scope.HideAddNew = false;" into the "hideData" function but that doesn't work. I have not yet tried ng-switch tho...

Comment: Hard to debug without seeing it an action. It sounds like `ng-switch` would be more elegant for your situation though. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: Thanx Tony, I'll try ng-switch and see if I can get that working nicely.

Comment: Welcome! I'll add it as an answer/potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could simplify and use [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) instead.

Something like this:

```
<ul ng-switch="expression">
  <li ng-switch-when="firstThing">my first thing</li>
  <li ng-switch-when="secondThing">my second thing</li>
  <li ng-switch-default>default</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, maybe you could use `ng-if` or `ng-show` instead of `ng-hide`, eg:

```
<p ng-if="HideAddNew">it's here!</p>
<p ng-if="!HideAddNew">it's not here.</p>
```

**Edit**

If I understand what you're trying to achieve *exactly*, I would use `ng-show` with an `ng-click`:

Controller:

```
$scope.addNew = false;
```

View:

```
<button ng-show="!addNew" ng-click="addNew = true">Add New</button> 

<button ng-show="addNew" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
<button ng-show="addNew" ng-click="addNew = false">Cancel</button>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raXEWK)

Comment: Thanx Tony. I would need something like the above. I edited my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanx for your help Tony, appreciate it but this is a lost cause I tell you, probably something stupid I'm doing. Here's a jsFiddle with my AngularJS and html: http://jsfiddle.net/zxw2hcta/

Comment: @jjay225 pleasure, I don't think I can help you anymore. Really hard to debug without being there in person, especially since you have a lot of api dependant stuff. If I were you I would start the view and controller from scratch with the `ng-click`'s and `ng-show` conditionals I suggested, and then combine that with your other functionality. :)

Comment: No worries, yeah it is hard to debug. Thanx tho Tony :) Cheers